# Forward value to the next shader

Tags: variables, glsl, shader

I want to pass values from the vertex shader to the fragment shader. Here is what I do for now.

```
#version 150

in vec2 texcoord;
out vec2 f_texcoord;

void main()
{
    f_texcoord = texcoord;
}
```

How can I reach the same behavior without defining two variable names `texcoord` and `f_texcoord` and eventually even get rid of the line `f_texcoord = texcoord;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GLSL the only way to pass attributes from the vertex shader to the fragment shader is exactly how you're doing it now - specially with texture coordinates since these usually change per-vertex (along with a position or normal in most cases).

For other properties, like colors or light positions, you could declare "global" variables instead by adding `uniforms` which can be used by both shaders without passing them as in-out pairs from vertex to fragment. Uniforms are usually constants that operate on a batch of vertices, rather than changing value per-vertex.

Comment: That's to bad. I thought a a syntax like `in out vec2 texcoord;` to make automatically forward it to the fragment shader.